# How does this proof show that $\inf_{\alpha \gt 0} \frac{f(\alpha x)}{\alpha}$ is homogenous?

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-optimization

How does this proof show that $\inf_{\alpha \gt 0} \frac{f(\alpha x)}{\alpha}$ is homogenous?

> Let $g(x) = \inf_{\alpha \gt 0} \frac{f(\alpha x)}{\alpha}$, $f$ be
>   a convex function, and $t \gt 0$.  Then $g$ is homogenous by:
>
> $$g(tx) = \inf \frac{f(\alpha t x)}{\alpha} = t\inf \frac{f(\alpha t
>  x)}{t\alpha} = tg(x) = t \inf \frac{f(\alpha x)}{\alpha}$$

But then it must be the case that

$$\inf_{\alpha} \frac{f(\alpha t x)}{t\alpha} =  \inf_{\alpha} \frac{f(\alpha x)}{\alpha}$$

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

$$\inf_{\alpha>0 }\frac{f(\alpha tx)}{t\alpha }=\inf_{t^{-1}u>0}\frac{f(ux)}{u}=\inf_{u>0}\frac{f(ux)}{u},$$
where the last equality comes from the fact that $t^{-1}u>0\iff u>0$.

Comment: How is $\large \inf_{\alpha \gt 0} \frac{f(\alpha t x)}{ta} = \inf_{t^{-1}u \gt 0} \frac{f(ux)}{u}$?

Comment: really ? Just set $u =t\alpha $

Comment: I see now.  And as you are new, I would suggest to review the stackexchange code of conduct.  https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: what do you mean with you "code of conduct" ?@OliverG

Comment: You talk about "code of conduct" because you felt insult (I still don't see by what), but you should read it your self and see that a good behavior is at least to say thank you or accept the answer if this answer to your original question. ;-)@OliverG

Comment: What I mean with code of conduct is the comment “really ?”.  In the code of conduct under “Our expectations” be kind and friendly and avoid sarcasm as tone is difficult to decipher online.  Additionally, under “unnaccetable behavior” avoid subtle put-downs or unfriendly behavior.  For future reference, you can simply say: Set $u=\alpha t$.

Comment: There is noting sarcastic in "really ?" ! This is just your crazy interpretation... Anyway, this conversation is just blow and boring !